# Where are the 'stock wallpapers' stored on the htc Desire S?

Tags: htc-desire, 2.3-gingerbread, wallpaper

I just bought an htc Desire S, which runs Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).  I can connect to FTP via BLuetooth's OBEX file transfer, or download one of the many file manager apps on the app store.  But one thing is driving me crazy.

When you 'Personalize', you get 'Scene', 'Wallpaper', and 'Skin' as the 2 top options.  I changed my wallpaper, so I clicked on Wallpaper, and selected 'HTC wallpapers'.

For the life of me I can't figure out where on the file system they are stored.  I wish to download them to my PC.  Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, what I ended up doing was using the ASTRO file manager app to access `/system/customize/resource` on my phone, which seems to have the wallpaper graphics (amongs a load of other stuff).  I copied the wallpaper I wanted to customize to an easy-to-reach place on the SD card (Edit | Copy, then Paste, in ASTRO), and copied it to my PC.  Customized the wallpaper, and then copied it to the sdcard's DCIM directory via a USB cable (you can also use Bluetooth for this).  I set it as my phone's background and it worked!  Yay!

Kudos to the people at [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/).

For those interested, I just wanted to have my phone's make/model display as part of the background.  Here's my new background wallpaper:

[image: New phone background]